# Issue: Invalid or incomplete login credentials

Tags: android, google-play-console

Getting error from play console even though I have provided login credentials for app access.

I have already provided login credentials

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have added the credential in right place,

**go to play console -> Select the app -> Select app content from Left menu -> then select App Access -> Then select -> All or some functionality is restricted ->Add new Instruction** ...

Comment: Thank you but i have added it at same place as you are suggesting

Comment: then may i see the report they send to you in mail, you can hide your privacy related thing